# how to move 2 circles on the screen independently of each other?

Tags: android, bitmap, touch-event

I've an app that paints 2 circles on the screen. once drawn I can move one of the circles around and place where i want. Is there a way to determin which circle I have touched so that I can move that particular circle? At the moment I can only move the circle at co-ords at centreX centreY.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
               if(xyFound == false) {
                centreX = (int) ev.getX()-70;
                centreY = (int) ev.getY()-70;
                xyFound = true;

               } else {
                centreA = (int) ev.getX()-70;
                centreB = (int) ev.getY()-70;
                abFound = true;
                bothCirclesInPlace  = true;
                invalidate();
               }
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if(xyFound == false){
                    centreX = (int) ev.getX()-70;
                    centreY = (int) ev.getY()-70;
                    xyFound = true;
                }else{
                    centreA = (int) ev.getX()-70;
                    centreB = (int) ev.getY()-70;
                    bothCirclesInPlace = true;
                    invalidate();
             }      break;

     }
```

.

**[update1]**

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {



        switch (ev.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {


                float circ1Val = centreX + centreY;
                float circ2Val = centreA + centreB;

                float choice1 = circ1Val - (ev.getX() + ev.getY());
                float choice2 = circ2Val - (ev.getX() + ev.getY());



                float circleToBeMoved = choice1 < choice2 ? ;
```

.
I'm not sure the best way to calculate the distance between each of the circles and the touch event. is this on the correct lines? or is there a better way? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the following approach:

On `ACTION_DOWN` you determine which circle lies next to the point touched. Therefore you calculate the distance from `(centreX,centreY)` to `(ev.getX(),ev.getY())` and from `(centreA,centreB)` to `(ev.getX(),ev.getY())`. If the first is smaller than the second you'll move the first circle otherwise the second circle (save this choice in a field `circleToBeMoved`). Maybe you want to reject any movement if both distances are beyond a threshold (e.g. radius of the circles).

Second, on `ACTION_MOVE` only move the circle contained in `circleToBeMoved` (if any).

Comment: hi, i've updated my post. any further help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: @turtleboy The correct way to calculate distance would be `distance1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ev.getX() - centreX, 2.0) + Math.pow(ev.getY() - centreY, 2.0))`.